# How to change resolution to 1920 x 1080?

Tags: 10.04, resolution

The display looks a bit stretched and there is a system pop-up that says something like "Resolution Notice: for best quality change resolution to 1920 x 1080" but in Monitor Preferences the only choices in the Resolution drop-down are 1600 x 1200 (the current setting), 1280 x 1024, and less (which all look worse). The monitor preferences calls the Monitor "unknown," the monitor is a ViewSonic [VX2450WM](http://www.viewsonic.com/products/vx2450wmled.htm),  and the PC is an [HP p7-1120](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/ca/en/ho/WF06b/12454-12454-3329740-64546-64546-5146449-5156972.html?dnr=1).

Comment: Can you mention how have you connected your monitor? (VGA or HDMI)

Comment: The connection is VGA. I also tried the HDMI connection which was not as good so I went back to VGA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English: What is your video card? He tried to make the driver update, you may need to install the manufacturer-supplied ...

Portuguese: Qual a sua placa de video? Tentou efetuar a atualização do driver, talvez seja necessário instalar o fornecido pelo fabricante...

Comment: The only thing it says in [HP p7-1120 specifications](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/ca/en/ho/WF06b/12454-12454-3329740-64546-64546-5146449-5156972.html?dnr=1) under `Graphics` is `Intel HD Graphics`.

Comment: Run the following command "lspci |grep VGA" and post the result. He will bring information about your video card that can assist in identifying the driver. I believe the chipset on your video card is the Sandy Bridge processor is seeing that his intel i3.

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sandy Bridge Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

Comment: Your questions provided the clue as to what to look for so I'll award bounty but have to wait till tomorrow. Found answer that worked after `sandy bridge ubuntu 10.04` search [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1747206&page=3).

Comment: Original source for solution: [Glasens Blog](http://www.glasen-hardt.de/?page_id=712).

Answer (score 2):

you can use [jupiter](http://www.jupiterapplet.org/) install it like so

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

logout and back in again 
and then on the top right corner you will have a new icon select
 
it and go to screen resolution and select your preferred resolution

this is the only app i use to change the resolution when needed.(I never used anything else) 
hope this works for you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the xorg-edgers repository of experimental drivers to update the drivers for your video card. Because the drivers are not guaranteed the experimental operation, can solve problems but also created new problems, but you sure are using the latest release of the same.

I own a laptop with this graphics card and recently updated the drivers for this repository, where there was no problem. If you want to perform the update run the command "sudo apt-add-repository ppa: xorg-edgers/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade-y" and restart your computer. After the restart the driver will be updated.

Your video card also has the technology SNA - Sandy Bridge New Acceleration Architecture that improves some acceleration features. After updating the driver to use this feature enter the command "sudo apt-add-repository ppa: sarvatt / sna-intel && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade-y"